# CSS: Overflowing block elements not style all the way

Tags: css, overflow

I tried to find an answer to my question, but I can't find it. Maybe I don't know how to ask. Here is a code example:

```css
ul{
  background: rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.1 );
}
li {
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li.selected {
  background: #ccccff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    LINE 1
    <ul>
      <li>
        LINE 1-1
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        LINE 1-2
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="selected">
    LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    LINE 3
    <ul>
      <li>
        LINE 3-1
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="selected">
        LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    LINE 4
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    LINE 5
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make the background color reach the end of the longest li element? Is there a trick? If I change the li to display: inline-block, then the colors reach the end, but short li elements will be on the same line. That is not desirable.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

UPDATED ...

It is working, but I don't know why exactly.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>Item ...</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            [CHILD LI ELEMENTS ...]
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or the version without the div element give me the desired result. The item's background-color is getting set all the way to the right.

```css
div#tree {
 position: fixed;
 top: 2em;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 0.5em;
 overflow: scroll;
}

ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul ul {
 margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

li {
 width: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
 list-style: none;
}

span {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0.25em;
 background: #336633;
 border: 0;
}
li.selected > div > span {
 background: #333366;
}
```

```html
<div id="tree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <div>
    <span>Root</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <span>ITEM 1</span>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>
                <span>ITEM 1-1</span>
              </div>
              <ul></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <span>ITEM 1-2 | ITEM 1-2 | ITEM 1-2 | ITEM 1-2 | ITEM 1-2</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <span>ITEM 2</span>
    </div>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Sorry for all the trouble. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify, Which background-color you're talking about?

Comment: The blue background should go all the way to the right.

Answer (score 1):

One best way to achieve this is update below css,

```
li {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
/* width */
li::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height:5px;
}
/* Track */
li::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
}
/* Handle */
li::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red; 
}
```

```css
ul{
  background: rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.1 );
}
li {
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
/* width */
li::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height:5px;
}
/* Track */
li::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
}
/* Handle */
li::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red; 
}
li.selected {
  background: #ccccff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    LINE 1
    <ul>
      <li>
        LINE 1-1
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        LINE 1-2
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="selected">
    LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    LINE 3
    <ul>
      <li>
        LINE 3-1
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="selected">
        LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    LINE 4
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    LINE 5
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is a very creative approach. But not exactly what I want. I put the "Line ..." text into a span and change the background of the span. And that seems to solve the problem. That easy, but on another project I tried exactly this and get the same cut background problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
li, 
li ul{
  background:rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.1 );
}
```

Comment: I can't see any change. When you scroll to the right, then the background-color stops in the middle and doesn't cover the overflow on the right. By the way, I am using Firefox on Ubuntu. The blue background should reach to the right. The red background is only for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul{
  background: rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.1 );
display:inline-block;
}
ul ul{
  display: block;
}
li {
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li.selected {
  background: #ccccff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    LINE 1
    <ul>
      <li>
        LINE 1-1
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        LINE 1-2
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="selected">
    LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2 | LINE 2
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    LINE 3
    <ul>
      <li>
        LINE 3-1
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="selected">
        LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2 | LINE 3-2
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    LINE 4
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    LINE 5
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or,

If same style required for all UL, use below.

```
ul{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```